# Cannot locate image inside a folder

Tags: c#, wpf, io, filepath

I need to add some new flag to [this](https://github.com/point-platform/famfamfam-flags-wpf) project, so I downloaded it and inserted the new image inside the `Images` folder. Each image name have the country ID available in `CountryData.cs`, this is the `Dictionary` structure:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _englishNameByIso2 = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        {"AF", "Afghanistan"},
        {"AX", "Åland Islands"},
        {"AL", "Albania"},
        {"DZ", "Algeria"},
        {"AS", "American Samoa"},
        ...
```

now I added a new line: `{"CW", "Curaçao"},` with an image file named: `cw.png` that I can see in the project folder. But when this code will be executed:

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var countryId = value as string;

        if (countryId == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            var path = $"/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/{countryId.ToLower()}.png";
            var uri = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative);
            var resourceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
            if (resourceStream == null)
                return null;

            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = resourceStream.Stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            return bitmap;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

it will return `null` for `IO Exception`, the other images are displayed correctly in the `ComboBox`.

I also tried to change the action build of the new image as resource but didn't worked.

The image in the folder doesn't have an action build setted. What am I doing wrong? I really don't understand why the new image are not found!

Comment: Why did you re-ask your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48215860/application-getresourcestream-always-return-null

Comment: @rene maybe adding new details I get help, don't think?

Comment: Just edit your old question then. Specially as someone might again  suggest to mark the files as Resource.

Comment: @rene so you have a time to search if I already posted a question, but doesn't have time to read my question and try to help, congrats. And also I wrote that I already tried the solution suggest and didn't worked

Comment: I'm trying to be as efficient as possible and as I recalled I had seen this before in a different context I started with a search yes, so I could offer an duplicate that I know had an answer. In that search your deleted question popped up. But I got the message, I'll stop searching and I hope someone will spot the typo in your code and offers it as an answer. Good luck!

Comment: @jjok, it is important to listen to senior members to understand how to get this community working effectively .. welcome :)

Comment: @Muds I know.. sorry rene, but I'm a bit frustrated by this issue that I can't able to fix, hope that you didn't take it :)

Comment: its all chill bro, keep asking, keep contributing, keep it simple :)

Comment: @Muds could you check my solution? https://ufile.io/tdlpv I tried all the hint..

Answer (score 1):

Set the image file's Build Action to *Resource*, and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf):

```
var path = $"pack://application:,,,/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf;component/Images/{countryId.ToLower()}.png";
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
```

Comment: You mean Embedded Resource? Change it to Resource for using Pack URIs. That's the way to load image file resources in WPF.

Comment: I've even the problem, could you help me?